# A polynomial decomposition into a product of at least $n$ irreducible polynomials.

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

There's this claim which I want to prove. The claim goes as follows:

Prove that the polynomial $x^{2^n}+x^{2^{n-1}}+1$ is a product of at least $n$ irreducible polynomials.

I was thinking something along the line of $(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)$ and then iterate it.

For $n=1$ it's $x^2+x+1$; for $x=2$ it's $x^4+x^2+1=(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)$.

So suppose that the assertion is correct for $n$ and prove it for $n+1$.

Now the induction step is where I am not sure, I know that $x^{2^n}+x^{2^{n-1}}+1$ by the induction hypothesis is a product of at least $n$ irreducible polynomials, but then how to show that $x^{2^{n+1}}+x^{2^n}+1=y^2+y+1$ where $y=x^{2^n}$ is a product of at least $n+1$ irreducible polynomials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use that
$$
(x^{2^n}-x^{2^{n-1}}+1)(x^{2^n}+x^{2^{n-1}}+1)=x^{2^{n+1}}+x^{2^n}+1
$$
for the induction. In fact, $x^{2^n}-x^{2^{n-1}}+1$ is irreducible. So we obtain exactly $n$ irreducible factors.